# Conditional Not Working

Tags: conditionals

I have an events listings. Events are by “start_date”. When I have no events I want to display “NO EVENTS SCHEDULED” When I have events I want to remove the NO EVENTS SCHEDULED. I can’t seem to get the conditionals right. Need help, can not seem to get my head around it.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel=“Events” sort="asc" orderby="start_date"}
{if star_date == ""} <h1>No Events Scheduled</h1>{/if}
{if start_date} <h4><strong>{title}</strong></h4>{/if}

{start_date format="%l, %F %j, %Y; %g:%i %a"}</><br>
{rentals_main_copy}
{if start_date} <span>New Vic, 33 W. Victoria Street, Santa Barbara, CA, 93101 (<a href="/visit/location">map</a>)</span> {/if}
{if start_date}<hr class="bottom-2">{/if}

 {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Your 1st conditional has a typo in it... missing the 't' from start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the search & no_results tag like this and do away with the multiple `{if}` statements:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="Events" sort="asc" orderby="start_date" search:start_date="not IS_EMPTY" }
  {if no_results} <h1>No Events Scheduled</h1>{/if}
  <h4><strong>{title}</strong></h4>{/if}

  {start_date format="%l, %F %j, %Y; %g:%i %a"}</><br>
  {rentals_main_copy}
  <span>New Vic, 33 W. Victoria Street, Santa Barbara, CA, 93101 (<a href="/visit/location">map</a>)</span>
  <hr class="bottom-2">

 {/exp:channel:entries}
```